# Is there a limitation on primary Category of a location in Google My Business (PlaceActionLinks) for creating Place Action Links?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am trying to create an "**APPOINTMENT**" action type link for the location we manage, following [this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/placeactions/rest/v1/locations.placeActionLinks/create) and I have this error

```
    {
  "code" : 400,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason" : "INVALID_LOCATION_CATEGORY"
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

the location's primaryCategory is `categories/gcid:womens_clothing_store`

I am sending the request via JAVA (suppose **myBusinessPlaceActions** is a variable which takes care of Authentication and initialising the API):

```
  PlaceActionLink link = new PlaceActionLink();
                    link.setUri("The APPONTMENT URL");
link.setPlaceActionType("APPOINTMENT"); 
        MyBusinessPlaceActions.Locations.PlaceActionLinks.Create requestCreate= myBusinessPlaceActions.locations().
                                placeActionLinks().create("locations/ MY LOCATIONID", link);
```

The Same Code is running correctly for other client and locations, for example a location with primary category =`categories/gcid:cosmetics_store`
or another client and location with category =`categories/gcid:spa_and_health_club`
What is wrong?

Comment: What kind of appointment would I make at a women's clothing store?

Comment: only APPOINTMENT. It is a link to the page that the user can book an appointment in a specific store(location), selecting from available dates and time. If you look at the [https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/placeactions/rest/v1/locations.placeActionLinks#PlaceActionType] you see the enum for the types which are predefined. and APPOINTMENT is one of them

Comment: I know what an appointment link on GBP is. I am referring to the primary category in question. It's disabled for a reason.

Comment: @vpriesner Sorry, I was explaining the link I am assigning as APPOINTMENT to the location we manage. for Example for another client where the location has a category gcid:clothing_store I created this link with no problem.

Comment: Are the two locations in the same country? It's possible that appointment links for clothing stores may be disabled for one country and enabled for another country.

Comment: no, you are right , they are not in the same country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message INVALID_LOCATION_CATEGORY indicates that this category in particular is not eligible for the "APPOINTMENT" place action type.

For a full list of error codes and their explanations, see the [Place Actions reference](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/placeactions/rpc/google.mybusiness.placeactions.v1#errorcode).

If you did manage to produce a place action link for a location with the category `categories/gcid:womens_clothing_store`, that location may either have a different category as well through which that place action link was created or that category might have place action links of that type enabled in one country and disabled in another country.